# PHP DateTime to Java Date

Tags: java, php, json, web-services

I have a PHP web service sending JSON responses back to my Java client. One of the fields is a DateTime value. However, I'm having problems translating the serialized PHP Date/Time to a Java Date.

For example, here is a date stored in my database:

`2011-12-07 15:03:01`

Here is how it's encoded in the JSON response:

`1323288181`

I suspected this would be the milliseconds since the Unix epoch, but when I construct a Java `Date` with that given value, the date turns out to be the following:

`Fri Jan 16 01:34:48 CST 1970`

Obviously it's not milliseconds since January 1, 1970 at midnight.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: It's the number of *seconds* since January 1, 1970.  http://www.epochconverter.com/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like that's *seconds* since the Unix epoch - so just multiply your value by 1000 when passing it to the `Date` constructor.

Note that `Date.toString()` will always use the system time zone, but a `Date` really represents an instant in time, so it doesn't *have* a time zone.

If you're doing anything *significant* with dates and times, I'd thoroughly recommend using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) instead of the classes in java.util.

Comment: Also makes sure that the value must be of type long like: `System.out.println(new Date(1323288181l*1000l));`

Comment: Yep, it's seconds. I can't believe I overlooked this! Definitely plan to use Joda Time as well. Thanks, Jon.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a unixtimestamp. use this online convertor: http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm

and here are examples how to convert it (in java):
http://www.epochconverter.com/

Answer (score 0):

I am using 
1970-01-01T00:00:00Z
as date time format in JSON,
then I make sure both sides parse it correctly